# Error in room Dao with lag function in query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have this query in my room Dao which contains both lag() and lead() functions

```
@Query("SELECT LAG(entry_word) OVER(ORDER BY entry_word) AS previous_word, entry_word AS current_word, LEAD(entry_word) OVER(ORDER BY entry_word) AS next_word FROM entry_words WHERE entry_word = :word") List<String> getEntryWords(String word);
```

But it shows me this error [image: query error]

How do I resolve this?

Edit: I'm now having this build error using my current query which says columns are returned instead of rows
[image: current build error]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Window functions were introduced in SQLite in version 3.25.0.
Probably you are using an older version of SQLite, so you can't use `LAG()` and `LEAD()`.
But, even if you could use them, your query is wrong and it would return `NULL` for `previous_word` and `next_word`.
The reason for this is because the `WHERE` clause filters the table and it returns **only 1 row** with `entry_word = :word` and then `LAG()` and `LEAD()` are applied which of course both return `NULL` since there is no previous and next row in the resultset.

The correct usage of `LAG()` and `LEAD()` in this case is with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT LAG(entry_word) OVER (ORDER BY entry_word) AS previous_word, 
         entry_word AS current_word, 
         LEAD(entry_word) OVER (ORDER BY entry_word) AS next_word 
  FROM entry_words 
)
WHERE current_word = :word
```

For versions of SQLite prior to 3.25.0 you can do the same with correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(e2.entry_word) FROM entry_words e2 WHERE e2.entry_word < e1.entry_word) AS previous_word, 
       e1.entry_word AS current_word, 
       (SELECT MIN(e2.entry_word) FROM entry_words e2 WHERE e2.entry_word > e1.entry_word) AS next_word 
FROM entry_words e1
WHERE e1.entry_word = :word
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried the second query you provided but ended up with a build error (please check new post edit)

Comment: @HaleemahAbdullahi my answer is for the question as you posted it. If you have a new problem you should ask a new question.